# Поиск символов в тексте и создания картинки C#

Tags: c#, массивы, изображения, поиск, текст

[image: Меню приложения]

Есть данное меню. Логика работы должна быть такая:

1. Юзер вводит текст в richbox.
2. Нажимает кнопку button
3. Программа ищет из RichBox.Text определенные символы (например "/", ">")
4. Программа вставляет изображения в ImageBox по этим символам в зависимости от порядка этих символов (изображения имеются в папке с exe файлом)

Нужна помощь в реализации поиска этих символов в тексте и создание картинки.
Пытался преобразовать текст в массив char (хотя string это уже набор массивов) и приравнивать к массиву Char с символами, которые необходимо найти, но работать это не стало.

Comment: Есть такая вещь, как `Contains()`. Создавайте массив, ну либо просто строку с нужными вам символами и простым перебором сверяете, есть ли подобный символ в этом созданном объекте. Можно еще и LINQ подключить, тогда вовсе одна строка: `"Крутой текст".Any(x=>"/>".Contains(x))`. Ну а вообще ваш вопрос довольно общий (ищем текст или создаем картинку?), расплывчатый и имеет много лишнего. Зачем например нам знать какой у вас дизайн приложения, о загрузке изображения и так далее, если вам просто надо узнать "есть ли символ в строке"?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо создать массив с символами, которые необходимо будет искать, и при нажатии на кнопку (если нужено составлять последовательность найденных символов) пройтись по содержимому текста с помощью цикла FOR

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char[] searchSymbols = new char[] { '<', '/', '\\', '>' };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = richTextBox1.Text;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (searchSymbols.Contains(text[i]))
            {
                Debug.Print($"На позиции {i} найден символ {text[i]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В следствии выполнения кода в консоли отладке будет следующий результат:

[image: результат вывода дебага]